# I'm using a MySQL table to log user data (1000 new rows / min). How can I rotate the rows after 2 days?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, innodb

To give you an example, say I have a site where the users can add unlimited cron jobs (frequency of 1s) and I log the results of each job in a Mysql table.

Now since I don't have unlimited storage (and also because I don't want my table to get huge) I want to restrict the logs history to last 30 days only.

Previously on an older version of Mysql, I was running `DELETE FROM logs where created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`, to clean my table, but this causes my tables to frequently crash and get corrupted. It also locks my table during `DELETE` which makes the site very slow.

Anyway, so how can I implement row rotation (like log rotation) for my Mysql table or rows? Is deleting rows my only option or are there some other option?

Comment: Cron job running every second?  And the user can put anything he wants into it?  That, itself, sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Move away from MyISAM to InnoDB; that should eliminate the corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a database partition

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-types.html

Example

```
PARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(column) )
```

This gives 7 partitions. Then you can simply

```
ALTER TABLE t1 TRUNCATE PARTITION p0;
```

To delete a single partition.

Comment: Hi, how will I delete logs older than 30 days with this? After seeing the linked page, I think I can do this: `CREATE TABLE logs (...) PARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(created_at) )` and then drop the preceding month?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just partition bu what ever values you want to be able to quickly drop

Comment: Would also want to point out that if you drop a months transactions on the 2nd you will only have 2 days of data. You may need to keep up tp 2 months this way. You could do weekly and keep up to 5 weeks of data to ensure you have the 30 days

Comment: `BY HASH` will not do any partition pruning, so it is not efficient.

Comment: @RickJames could you please elaborate on that? Will it be able to insert 1000 rows / min? Would appreciate if there is anything I should be aware before I start implementing this.. thanks!

Comment: 1000/min is slow; 1000/second would be somewhat challenging.  HASH does not prune well in some situations.  My Answer has a link with more info.

Answer (score 1):

[*This*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) discusses use of `PARTITION BY RANGE` as a very efficient way of "deleting" old data.  It explains how to do `DROP PARTITION` (which is more efficient than `TRUNCATE`) and create a new partition each day or week.